# Log the complete word in regex

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hey I'm pretty new to regex so I need help. I want to match a part of my string and then logs it after, the problem is it doesn't log the word after the regex. Here's my code :

```
const regex = /yes/;
const text = "do you think its yesorno";
const contains = regex.exec(text);
const result = contains[0];
console.log(result)
```

So I want the result to be "yesorno". Anyone can help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can match the word until a space character or end of the sentence:

```
/yes.*?(?=(?: |$))/
```

**Where:**

`yes` - matches the characters yes literally (case sensitive)

`.*?` - matches any character (except for line terminators)

`(?=(?: |$))`  - **Positive Lookahead**

`(?: |$)` - **Non-capturing group**

**1st Alternative** -   (space)

(space) matches the character  (space) literally

**2nd Alternative - $**

`$` asserts position at the end of a line

```js
const regex = /yes.*?(?=(?: |$))/;
const text = "do you think its yesorno";
const contains = regex.exec(text);
const result = contains[0];
console.log(result)
```